# How to fetch the substring

Tags: php

In my code I have a statement like this:

```
$last_100_char = substr($str[0], -100);
```

I want to retrieve the last 100 characters of the first element of an array, but while doing this I,m getting some error

> substr() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given.

how to fix this?

Comment: check `$str[0]` value. what is in `$str[0]`?

Comment: most likely `$str[0]` is still an array, `print_r($str)` to find out

Comment: add `$str` variable in question

Comment: $str[0] is a very big string, so I want to retrieve oly last 100 characters...

Answer (score 0):

The error has occurred because the first parameter ie, `$str[0]` is still an array. As another more efficient method, to obtain the first element of an array you can use `array_shift()` method.

```
$first=array_shift(array_values($array));
echo substr($first, -100);
```

Comment: Then the problem is with your array. Please share the array values.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is working fine when I test it.

Make sure that your `$str[0]` actually contains a string by doing `print_r( $str );`

Comment: It is a string but why I,m getting that error message..?

Comment: Could you please paste your entire code including the array, and the output of print_r?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer

Initially I did

```
$str[] = explode(';',$job_record ['JD']);

$last_100_char = substr($str[0], -100);
```

So I'm getting that error..

Now I made it as

```
$str['data']=explode(';',$job_record ['JD']);

$last_100_char = substr($str['data'][0], -100);
```

Now I'm getting the correct output...

Comment: You can simply do it like `$str=explode(';',$job_record ['JD']);
$last_100_char = substr($str[0], -100);`